# Comparing row count for DB2 and Hive

Tags: shell, hadoop, hive, hiveql, sqoop

I am trying to write a shell script where i am comparing the DB2 and Hive row counts and checking if they are matching or not.
While doing the same, i am facing an issue with hive count.

As i am taking hive count in a text file, its coming in below format:

```
+---------+--+
|   _c0   |
+---------+--+
| 713313  |
+---------+--+
```

After that i changed the property in from table to CSV(beeline --outputformat=tsv) and now the output is like this:

```
'_c0'
'713313'
```

is there any way where we can get only the count? i dont want to use AWK or GREP or SED to extract the records count. Please do let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Shortest way:

count=`hive -S -e 'select count(*) from database.table_name'`

Comment: Thanks for replying this quick.                                                                   The output is still same. [****@**** test_count]$ echo $count
+------+--+ | _c0 | +------+--+ | 421 | +------+--+                                                               I want to extract only count.